# Retrieving document which contains a specified field in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee

How can I retrieve documents which contains a given key in MongoDB collection? I'm using Mongodb Java driver. I know how to retrieve documents by key value ,but i'm not sure how to return all the documents which contains a given key?

Eg: Document1 has keys name, age. Document2 has keys name, age and place. I need to retrieve documents which has key : place, so that I will get document2 as the result. How can I query this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use $exists to check whether a key is present in the document or not.

```
DBObject queryObject = new BasicDBObject("place", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));
DBCursor result = collection.find(queryObject);
```

Comment: Or you can use QueryBuilder -  `QueryBuilder.start("place").exists(true).get()` to build `queryObject`